# How to calculate RC filter time constant of parallel battery cell filters

Tags: filter, low-pass, passive-filter, calculation

I am working on cell balancing circuit for a stack of LiIon cells.
The filters are used in front of and ADC input to filter the cell voltage.
The datasheet claims that with given values the cutoff frequency should be 80kHz.
If I calculate the cutoff frequency for one filter, pretending that the others don't exist, I get 39.79kHz (1/(2*pi*2*R*C).
Is this a wrong approach?
How would you calculate a filter cutoff frequency of a single filter in this kind of network?
[image: Schematic]

Comment: How are the ADCs connected and what sort of input stage is each ADC? If it's LTSpice that you are using then why not simulate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cutoff frequency of stacked low pass RC filters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524737/cutoff-frequency-of-stacked-low-pass-rc-filters)

Comment: When I simulate the circuit as described in that question, by shorting all sources except one, I get -3dB at 34 to 37kHz for each filter in stack.
The datasheet of the IC claims that inside is just an ADC with 2MΩ input resistance. No other elements in front of it.

Comment: @Andyaka I would vote as duplicate, but that question also doesn't have an answer, and the one comment isn't a great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single-pole response, so 'cutoff frequency' isn't clearly defined, but let's assume its the -3dB point.

Imagine you are calculating the response to VCEL3. You are correct to short all the other V sources. Clearly then, this puts additional elements in parallel with both R5 and R6 -- lowering the effective value of each. Thus the simple calculation using just (1/(2pi2RC) is not correct.

To calculate, you'd have to do a full KCL analysis of the circuit which is a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the chip supplier and they said that since ADC's are operating at the same time, the currents in shared branches cancel out. Effectively each filter is then made of one R and one C. This gives the calculated corner frequency of 79.577 kHz (~80kHz) as they claim in the datasheet.
[image]

Currents on R6 should cancel out. They recognize that there would be some cross influence between the filters, but they are not concerned about that since their goal was to have the corner frequency less than 80kHz.
But I don't believe that their theory of currents cancelling out is correct. If we look at the complete battery stack (next picture) currents in all resistors except R7 and R4 should cancel out.

[image]

So we would effectively have just two resistors (the first one and the last one) and a capacitor array. Source Vcell3 would then have only C4 as a filter.

Comment: You need look at the filtering from the perspective of a single Vcell. A Vcell in the 'middle' does have 2 resistors filtering it plus the other components above and below.

However you also could consider the source of noise in such a system -- it's generally caused by surges of load current which flow through all cells and perhaps generate equal (& correlated) noise signals in each individual cell. In that case, the shared R's will 'cancel', and the only effective filtering is from the very top and bottom R's (R7 & R4) driving SERIES caps (effectively 2.5 nF.

There is no single answer.